# r and igraph Help, Assortativity Coefficient with Weighted Edges. Remaining weights vs. Total weights. (undirected graph)

Tags: r, graph, igraph, network-analysis

a combo network analysis and igraph/r question. It is [cross posted with Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361491/graph-theory-help-assortativity-coefficient-with-weighted-nodes-remaining-weig) (and I will hopefully not be laughed away).

I am trying to find the assortativity coefficient for an undirected weighted graph. Edges are have weights, reflecting flows of value between nodes (if you're curious, it's a graph of a marketplace with goods being exchanged between traders).

I see the standard [Newman (2002)](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0205405) implementation of assortativity may be applied to weighted networks, replacing degree count with degree strength, ala

[image: formula]

(where *i* indexes the graph's *M* edges, and F(i) denotes the set of two nodes connected by link *i*, and *s_\phi is strength or total weights; the sum of edge weights connected to node \phi*.)

And I see this implemented by the r package [igraph](https://github.com/cran/igraph/blob/ffa6adb9c4294310ea6b8884e1b6457fa190e261/src/mixing.c), via the `assortativity(g, types1 = graph.strength(g))`, where types1 are node weights.

## The issue

If *s_\phi* were just degrees, one could either use total or remaining degrees and you'd get the same answer either way. However, using total weight (`graph.strength(g)` above), I am worried about introducing upward bias in my assortativity metric, since each node weight includes the edge weight we are iterating over (the edge which connects those two nodes). Although I can't point to a citation at the moment, it seems like we should be finding the correlation of remaining weights.

That is to say, where *s_\phi* above is the sum of weights on edges connected to node *\phi* including the edge that connects them, it should be the remaining weights; the sum of weights on edges connected to node *\phi*, except for edge *i*.

---

Firstly, I am curious if this is an issue? Working with this type of graph, will assortativity using nodes weights bias up my correlation estimate? Does it just not matter?

---

Secondly, I am curious if this is possible with the igraph package in r, or the networkX python library. Perhaps an implementation of weighted degree-dependent nearest-neighbors degree?  Doesn't look like it, but thought I'd ask.

---

I put together an example to show you what I mean:

### Set up

```
library(igraph)

g <- read.table(
  text = 
  " a b c d e f
  a 0 4 5 8 1 0
  b 4 0 1 4 8 9
  c 5 1 0 4 1 0
  d 8 4 4 0 2 7
  e 1 8 1 2 0 1
  f 0 9 0 7 1 0
  ",
  header = T

  )

g <- as.matrix(g)
g <- graph.adjacency(g, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE)

E(g)$width <- E(g)$weight; plot(g)
```

### igraph

```
assortativity.degree(g) # degree assortativity (ie unweighted)
[1] -0.4444444

assortativity(g, types1 = graph.strength(g), directed = F) #assortativity with weights
[1] -0.2421219
```

### my remaining weights assortativity

```
assortativity.weightEdge <- function(g){

  linkedNodes <- data.frame(
    n1 = rep(NA, length(E(g))),
    n2 = rep(NA, length(E(g))),
    s1 = rep(NA, length(E(g))),
    s2 = rep(NA, length(E(g))),
    s1_remaining = rep(NA, length(E(g))),
    s2_remaining = rep(NA, length(E(g))),
    k_nn_1 = rep(NA, length(E(g))),
    k_nn_2 = rep(NA, length(E(g)))
  )


  # standard Newman 2002, http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0205405v1.pdf
  # but usign the "remaining strengths"
  num1 = 0
  num2 = 0
  den1 = 0  

  #iterate over edges
  for (i in 1:length(E(g))){

    n1 = ends(g,E(g))[i,1]
    n2 = ends(g,E(g))[i,2]

    s1 = sum(g[n1,]) - g[n1,n2] # stregth of "remaining" connected nodes 
    s2 = sum(g[n2,]) - g[n1,n2] #   "

    linkedNodes$n1[i] <- n1
    linkedNodes$n2[i] <- n2
    linkedNodes$s1_remaining[i] <- s1
    linkedNodes$s2_remaining[i] <- s2

    num1 = num1 + s1 * s2
    num2 = num2 + s1 + s2
    den1 = den1 + (s1^2 + s2^2)    

  }

  num1 = num1 / length(E(g))
  num2 = num2 / (length(E(g)) * 2)
  num2 = num2 * num2
  den1 = den1 / (length(E(g)) * 2)

  print(
    paste(
      "Assortativity, remaining weights:",
      (num1-num2) / (den1-num2))
    )  

  ##########

  num1 = 0
  num2 = 0
  den1 = 0  

  #iterate over edges
  for (i in 1:length(E(g))){

    n1 = ends(g,E(g))[i,1]
    n2 = ends(g,E(g))[i,2]

    s1 = sum(g[n1,])
    s2 = sum(g[n2,])

    linkedNodes$s1[i] <- s1
    linkedNodes$s2[i] <- s2

    num1 = num1 + s1 * s2
    num2 = num2 + s1 + s2
    den1 = den1 + (s1^2 + s2^2)    

  }

  num1 = num1 / length(E(g))
  num2 = num2 / (length(E(g)) * 2)
  num2 = num2 * num2
  den1 = den1 / (length(E(g)) * 2)

  print(
    paste(
      "Assortativity, total weights:",
      (num1-num2) / (den1-num2))
  )  

  return(linkedNodes)

}
```

## returns:

```
assortativity.weightEdge(g)
[1] "Assortativity, remaining weights: -0.3579013116802"
[1] "Assortativity, total weights: -0.242121917988836"
   n1 n2 s1 s2 s1_remaining s2_remaining k_nn_1 k_nn_2
1   a  b 18 26           14           22     NA     NA
2   a  c 18 11           13            6     NA     NA
3   a  d 18 25           10           17     NA     NA
4   a  e 18 13           17           12     NA     NA
5   b  c 26 11           25           10     NA     NA
6   b  d 26 25           22           21     NA     NA
7   b  e 26 13           18            5     NA     NA
8   b  f 26 17           17            8     NA     NA
9   c  d 11 25            7           21     NA     NA
10  c  e 11 13           10           12     NA     NA
11  d  e 25 13           23           11     NA     NA
12  d  f 25 17           18           10     NA     NA
13  e  f 13 17           12           16     NA     NA
```

For some evidence, note the total weights assortativity matches igraph's. And as suspected, the remaining weights assortativity is a bit lower than that derived with total weights.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you seen this: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437106013707

Comment: I have (I actually prefer their notation over Newman's). They suggest checking weighted degree-dependent nearest-neighbor degree, and suggest a version of  weighted assortativity coefficient (eq 15) that applies edge weights to (total) node degree. Since I'm curious about correlations of trading and trader size (strength, not degree), I don't think suggestion makes much sense in this application. Thanks for help!

Comment: Just wanted to point out Noldus and Van Mieghem (2015) also have a nice survey of these topics. https://www.nas.ewi.tudelft.nl/people/Piet/papers/JCN2015AssortativitySurveyRogier.pdf